# How can I use a static C++ method as a callback for a Poco timer?

Tags: timer, poco-libraries

Particularly I'm talking about the constructor of this Poco class: [Poco.TimerCallback](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.TimerCallback.html)

I would like to use it in legacy C++ code where most of the classes I've written are "static" so that they only contain static methods and no constructors, just because I won't need multiple instances of such objects anyway, and the classes are merely for encapsulation. Well yeah, the Poco guys suggest to add a callback method like this:

```
TimerCallback<MyClass> callback(*this, &MyClass::onTimer);
timer.start(callback);
```

Do I understand this code snippet correctly: `MyClass::onTimer` may also be a static method of `MyClass`, but I also need the current instance of `MyClass`, so that methods of static classes, which are not instantiated, are simply banned from being used as a `TimerCallback`, or am I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not call it "banned" - the function callbacks are just not implemented, and there is nothing preventing you to implement it yourself (and send it back as a contribution, if you are inclined to do so).

I'd just extend the [TimerTaskAdapter](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.1/Util/include/Poco/Util/TimerTaskAdapter.h), so that it does not require object instance, eg. something like this:

```
typedef void (*FunctionCallback)(TimerTask&);
TimerTaskAdapter(FunctionCallback func): _pObject(0), _method(0), _func(func){}
...
FunctionCallback _func;
```

Then detect in `TimerTaskAdapter::run()` what is null and whether to call the method or function:

```
void run()
{
    if (_pObject) (_pObject->*_method)(*this);
    else (*_func)(*this);
}
```

Comment: OK, so I would formulate a class, which inherits from `TimerTaskAdapter`, and then override the `run()` method of the original adapter class with what you suggested me, right?

Comment: you can do that. since the change is generic and a feature worth adding to the framework, you can also modify the TimerTaskAdapter and send pull with changes to be included in the future releases.

Comment: Then I would create a `Poco.Util.Timer` and `schedule ()` an instance of my `TimerTask Adapter` derivative, right?

Comment: You don't need to derive anything on the user side, just wrap it in adapter: `TimerTask::Ptr pTask = new TimerTaskAdapter<YourClass>(&YourClass::onTimer); timer.schedule(pTask, time);` - similar as before, just no instance (as you wanted). (I'm typing this off the top of my head, but it should work.)

Answer (score 0):

After running into a much more nasty problem (related to pointers to class members) when extending `TimerTaskAdapter`, someone suggested to derive my class from `TimerTask` directly: [Pointer to member type incompatible with object type → What is the cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53141938/pointer-to-member-type-incompatible-with-object-type-%E2%86%92-what-is-the-cause)

See this sourcecode:

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.h:

```
// Header file for ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp class file.
// This is an extension of the Poco::Util::TimerTask class.

#include <Poco/Util/Timer.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTask.h>

#ifndef PROCEDURALTIMERTASKADAPTER_H
#define PROCEDURALTIMERTASKADAPTER_H

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Util;

typedef void (*Callback) (TimerTask&);

namespace Poco {
  namespace Util {
    class ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter : public TimerTask {
    public:
      ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (Callback procedure); // Constructor

      void run (); // Method defining the main thread
    protected:
      ~ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (); // Destructor (not for general use)
    private:
      ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (); // Default constructor (not for general use)

      Callback procedure; // The callback procedure called by the timer.
    };
  }
}

#endif
```

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp:

```
// This is the implementation of the ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter class.

#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Util/Timer.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTask.h>
#include "ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Util;

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (Callback proc) :
  TimerTask::TimerTask (),
  procedure (proc)
{
}

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::~ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter ()
{
}

void ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::run ()
{
  procedure (*this);
}
```

It worked out of the box. Nevertheless thank you for your answers & comments!