# Pointer to member type incompatible with object type → What is the cause?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, poco-libraries

Recently I ran into a compiler (GNU g++ 4.9.2) error like this:

```
ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp:25:13: error: pointer to member type ‘void (Poco::Util::Timer::)(Poco::Util::TimerTask&)’ incompatible with object type ‘Poco::Util::ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter’
```

Here is the relevant code (which is almost self-contained, save for the necessary Poco libs):

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.h:

```
#include <Poco/Util/Timer.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTask.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTaskAdapter.h>

#ifndef PROCEDURALTIMERTASKADAPTER_H
#define PROCEDURALTIMERTASKADAPTER_H

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Util;

typedef void (*Callback) (TimerTask&);

namespace Poco {
  namespace Util {
    class ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter : public TimerTaskAdapter <Timer> {
    public:
      ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (Callback procedure); // Constructor

      void run (); // Method defining the main thread
    protected:
      ~ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (); // Destructor (not for general use)
    private:
      ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (); // Default constructor (not for general use)

      Callback procedure; // The callback procedure called by the timer.
    };
  }
}

#endif
```

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp:

```
// This is the implementation of the ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter class.

#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Util/Timer.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTask.h>
#include <Poco/Util/TimerTaskAdapter.h>
#include "ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::Util;

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter (Callback procedure) : TimerTaskAdapter<Timer>::TimerTaskAdapter (*(new Timer ()), procedure)
{
  this -> procedure = procedure;
}

ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::~ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter ()
{
}

void ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::run ()
{
  TimerTask &task = *this;

  (this ->* procedure) (task);
}
```

What I wanna do is, in fact, build an extension of the well-known `TimerTaskAdapter` to handle callback functions, which are *not* tied to a specific class (because they are situated in `main.cpp`, for instance). I override the virtual method `run ()` with a very simple self-made one, which calls the callback. After having handled several different errors, I ended up with this apparent class mismatch I can't solve myself. I even don't understand why the compiler states a class name, whose name is `Poco::Util::Timer::` (Why does it end with `::`?). As `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter` defines a member named `procedure`, why does the compiler expect another class?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the line of the error first.

Comment: `this ->* procedure`. `procedure` if of `Callback` type, that is `void (*)(TimerTask&)`. It is not bind to `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter` object. Probably you meant to do `void (ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::*)(TimerTask&)` type. Learn about [pointers to members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members).

Comment: @Kamil Cuk: Don't forget what I wrote below the code: The `procedure` must be some function, which takes a `TimerTask&` as one arg, and returns `void`. It will be handed over in my class' constructor from some (maybe completely different) piece of code. And yes, I'm not very proficient in pointers to members. I have already looked into similar issues like http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/20404/, which, unfortunately, did not help me much.

Comment: Please provide a MVCE (emphasis on compilable).

Comment: Try to replace `(this ->* procedure) (task);` with `(this -> procedure) (task);` or shorter simply `procedure(*this);`

Comment: No use with your last suggestion, @Walter: In both cases, the compiler wants a `.*` or a `->*`. Sorry! :-(

Comment: @Neppomuk the problem is that you failed to provide a MCVE. Lacking that, I had assumed that your code was otherwise correct, i.e. that `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter` was derived from `TimerTask` (when my suggestion and your code makes sense). However, now I understand (from other answers) that your code was wrong in a way that one could only detect with an MVCE or insider knowledge (as rafix07 had).

Comment: Deriving from `TimerTaskAdapter` itself was not the error. In fact, in my previous questtion regarding this matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132421/how-can-i-use-a-static-c-method-as-a-callback-for-a-poco-timer I was originally advised to extend `TimerTaskAdapter`, so I followed this advice. You can even see this in the code I placed in my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from `Poco::Util::TimerTask` (like in `Poco::Util::TimerTaskAdapter` class) and override `run` method in which you will call procedures.

```
class ProcedureAdapter : public Poco::Util::TimerTask {
public:

    typedef void (*Callback)(TimerTask&);

    ProcedureAdapter (Callback c) : callback(c) {;}

    void run () {
        callback(*this); // call some procedure which takes TimerTask
    }

    Callback callback;
};

void fun (Poco::Util::TimerTask&) {
    cout << "fun was invoked" << endl;
}

void fun2 (Poco::Util::TimerTask&) {
    cout << "fun2 was invoked" << endl; 
}

int main()
{
    Poco::Util::Timer t;
    t.schedule (new ProcedureAdapter{&fun},1,1);
    t.schedule (new ProcedureAdapter{&fun2},1,1);
```

Comment: :-/ I'm slightly puzzled about some details of your answer: The constructor `ProcedureAdapter (Callback c)` is _not_ tied to any constructor of the base class `Poco::Util::TimerTask`, right? Then you would call `TimerTask`'s default constructor implicitly. And: What for are you enclosing constructor params in curly braces: `new ProcedureAdapter{&fun}`

Comment: @Neppomuk `TimerTask` is base class of ProcedureAdapter, so its ctor is called implicitly when ProcedureAdapter object is created. You don't need to call `TimerTask` ctor by yourself. Curly braces - this is a form of initialization since C++11, in above code is the same as `new ProcedureAdapter(&fun),..`. Your mistake in your code was that you derived from `TimerTaskAdapter`, because this class was designed to handle calling methods for objects, not free-functions, you should not derive from this class because then your adapter holds pointer to object and callback, when you want only callback.

Comment: OK, @rafix07: Thank you for the hints! In fact, someone else advised me to extend `TimerTaskAdapter` to make work easier, but this now turned out not to be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Neppomuk no problem, Poco libraries are very readable, you can open source code and check how things are implemented :) .

Comment: OK, this wasn't maybe the exact answer to my original problem, but at least the new code (which now inherits from `TimerTask`) compiles. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `->*` expects a left-hand operator of type pointer to class object (such as `this`) and a right-hand operator of type pointer to member function of that class. But in

```
TimerTask &task = *this;          // line 24
(this ->* procedure) (task);      // line 25
```

`procedure` is not a pointer to a member function of `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter`. So your code is ill-formed. `procedure` is simply a pointer to a free (non-member) function taking a `TimerTask&` and returning `void`. **If `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter` is derived from 
`TimerTask`** then the following code should compile

```
TimerTask &task = *this;
(this -> procedure) (task);
```

or shorter

```
procedure(*this);
```

using the fact that pointers to functions can syntactically be used like the function.

---

Edit. It appears (from your comments to another answer) that your code was ill-formed in yet another way, namely that `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter` was not derived from `TimerTask`. Then, of course already line 24 (not just 25) should produce an error. It seems, therefore, that you didn't show us the precise same code as the one that created the error message, or not all the errors it causes.

Comment: No use: Your short-hand alternative generates an error message like this: `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp:25:19: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((Poco::Util::ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter*)this)->Poco::Util::ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter::procedure (...)’` And your suggestion to use `->` leaves me with a very similar one: `ProceduralTimerTaskAdapter.cpp:25:28: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function`